# Edubuntu and Firefox add ons help

Tags: 12.04, edubuntu, ltsp, firefox-extensions

I have installed Edubuntu 12.04 and have ltsp working.  This is installed in a classroom setting and I would like to use a content filter in Firefox as an add on.  The add on I would like to use is ProCon.  The problem that I am having is that I Would like to install this add on globally to Firefox and not have to install it on every user account.  Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions how to install extensions for all users are found on following url,
however this disables the automatic update of the extensions and needs manual 
upgrades.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_extensions#Linux

Comment: just to add the fact in the link privided by ThinLinc the folder is in your case : /usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{AppId} . About the AppId thing you must install it in your session and then You'll be able to find the appid folder of your extension over there : ~/.mozilla/ . Just copy the "appid" folder into the folder that I've mentioned and do a chmod -R 755 appid folder and you should have it for everyone.